# Call @IBAction function without pressing the button

Tags: swift, function, button, ibaction

How i can call `button1()` func from `calc()` with original `sender`(like if i tap this button)? Call func with `nil` is bad soulution, because original sender is lost and i cant change button image through `sender?.image = UIImage(named: "")`.

All answers in others topics offer use  `button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)`. But this solution isn't working.

```
var var1 = true
var var2 = 1

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem?) {

    if var2 == 1 {

        sender?.image = UIImage(named: "1")

    } else {
        sender?.image = UIImage(named: "2")
    }

}


func calc() {

    if var1 {
        button1(nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make outlet of button and pass the reference as sender

```
@IBOutlet var outletButton: UIButton!

func calc() {

    if var1 {
        button1(outletButton)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var var1 = true
var var2 = 1


@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem?) {
    button1Action()
}

func button1Action() {
    if var2 == 1 {
        sender?.image = UIImage(named: "1")

    } else {
        sender?.image = UIImage(named: "2")
    }
}


func calc() {
    if var1 {
        button1Action()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call`self.perform(Selector, with: self)`